# Problemas al inicializar una app con Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Les cuento que tengo un problema al inicializar una app creada en Android Studio que incluye una base de datos Firebase realtime, este es el código:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FbTextV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TvFire);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mRootChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // El problema esta en las siguientes 2 lineas
                String texto = (String)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                FbTextV.setText(texto);
                // String texto = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

El problema esta en que cuando intento abrir la aplicación en el emulador esta se cierra de inmediato y ademas Android Studio no reconoce ningún tipo de error, por favor si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería muchas gracias

Comment: ¿No será más bien un problema del emulador que no funciona en sí? ¿Funciona con otra app? ¿Probaste en un dispositivo físico, conectado vía USB?

Comment: Buenas este https :// youtu.be/5aNKXc62iWU tio lo espelica bien como configurar firebare y vincular la id con de la cuenta con la aplicación es en arabe pero fejate buen el lo ultimo si ya tienes la cuenta y es solo vincular sin que te salga el error que te da ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente te este tirando nulo cuando usas dataSnapshot.getValue()

Por lo que pude ver en la documentación la correcta manera de obtener el valor sería

```
 dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```